# AccessToken changes between calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

With the Facebook C# SDK, are you supposed to create an instance many times?

app = new Facebook.FacebookApp();

When I do, i get a new accessToken in the session and then i get an error

{"Error validating access token."}

Has anyone seen this?

12/7/2010 - Update on this error.  I'm able to replicate this.  It is related to login in and out with two user accounts and keeping the checkbox for "Keep me logged in" selected.

I have modified the Facebook.Samples.MvcFacebookApp given with the SDK to reproduce.  Nathan if there is a way i can send you this or post it somewhere let me know.

How to replicate while debugging in Visual Studio (running localhost on port 8181)

1. Login with User 1 with "Keep me logged in" selected.
2. Make calls to the Graph API (like getting user information) - this should prompt for granting permissions.
3. Log out.
4. Stop debugging
5. Run project and log in with User 2 with "Keep me logged in" selected.
   **IMPORTANT:** This user is new to app and you would expect for the permissions prompt that never will show.
6. Perform same action that calls Graph API to get user info (name, picture, etc.) as before with this user.
7. You get the 'Error Validating access token' message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of FacebookApp with the default constructor as long as you are in the context of an HttpRequest to read the access token.

There shouldn't be a problem with what you are doing, but if you include more code I could be more specific.

Comment: I have talked to another developer where he sees this happen intermittently.  Today this is not happening for me and yesterday was the first time.  He mentioned that once it happens it will continue to happen until the next day. 


Because of this, I think it may be related to cached cookies, so we will try to remove them next time it happens.  


If I can replicate, I'll try to put a simple example to send or post here.

Thanks again and great work with the SDK!

Comment: Sounds good. Any "hard" evidence would help. I know there have been a number of people who have talked about this issue, but I have never really been able to reproduce it. I also have a few FB apps that have 25k+ users per day and haven't seen it.

Comment: Nathan, this usually happens for me when the user has logged in the app and then while still there, the user logs out form facebook. The app still believes the user is logged in and authentication just lets him pass. Then when he calls FacebookApp.Api() he gets the Exception mentioned above. Is there any way to make sure the user is looged out from facebook even when the app says he is still in??

Comment: Carlos, I just tried this and had no luck. I'm logged in, with the "keep me logged in" option, so opening a browser and going to FB does not require another login.

After that I get the error again.  I was fine this monring, and it does not look related to coockies etc, since clearing them prior to login into FB does not help.

Comment: Nathan, I still get this problem several times a day, but not consistently.  This is why I'm not sure if sending or posting code would help.  How would you troubleshoot this? Looking at data being sent over HTTP?  Any advices is appreciated.

Comment: I get this debugging the Facebook projects:


-  Headers {Pragma: no-cache
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 78
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2010 21:12:12 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Set-Cookie: datr=rFH9TKmim57E2oJbORJ2MidB; expires=Wed, 05-Dec-2012 21:12:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "Error validating access token."

} System.Net.WebHeaderCollection